# How to perform a full text search in MongoDb with C# Lambda expression

Tags: c#, mongodb, lambda, mongodb-.net-driver

There are a lot of answers how to get full-text search using Mongodb Driver Builders.
But it has another way of ORM is lambdaexpressions to filter query.

```
var collection = _mongoContextFactory.GetCollection<Foo>();
collection.FindSync(x => x.Created >= new DateTime());
```

So How I will can to get full-text search using lambda ( I use specification pattern that provides expression interface)

Comment: don't think it's possible. `Builders<T>.Filter.Text` is the only way afaik.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I tried to find solution inside `ExpressionFilterDefinition` (`MongodbDriver` converts lambda expression to this filter) and was defeated.

So, directly full text search is not supported by lambda expression. I switched on my imagination and created workaround for this task. 
I made abstract class for dto entity that utilize Full-Text index

```
  public abstract class FullTextSearchEntity
    {
        [BsonElement("$text"), BsonIgnoreIfNull]
        public FullTextSearchOption FullTextSearch { get; set; }
    }
```

As You can guess `FullTextSearchOption` repeats BSON structure for utilize fulltext index

```
  public class FullTextSearchOption
    {
        [BsonElement("$search"), BsonIgnoreIfNull]
        private string Search { get; set; }

        public FullTextSearchOption(string search)
        {
            Search = search;
        }
    }
```

And finally I added specification for usage this workaround:

```
  public class FullTextSearchSpecification<T> : SpecificationBase<T> where T: FullTextSearchEntity
    {
        private readonly string _searchQuery;

        public FullTextSearchSpecification(string searchQuery)
        {
            _searchQuery= searchQuery;
        }

        public override Expression<Func<T, bool>> ToExpression()
        {
            return entity=> entity.FullTextSearch == new FullTextSearchOption(_searchQuery);
        }
    }
```

Bingo!